# How to programmatically clear the Camera cache in Android?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I have an issue with Samsung Galaxy tablets. When my application triggers the camera flash, the image gets dark. I never noticed this issue since I was doing testing with other brands. But, recently, I just stared testing with Samsung Galaxy and I found out that issue.

After several days doing research I found that one way to temporally solve it could be clearing the camera cache. Effectively, that works if you do it through the device camera setting, but I need to do it now by code, since I would like to trigger that event before the user uses the camera flash.

How can I accomplish that programmatically ?